# Non-Flickering Polling in Angular with REST Backend

Tags: rest, angularjs, polling, flicker

I managed getting a constant polling of the backend functional using
[this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13671558/1126545)

But on every timeout the UI is flickering (empty model for a short time).
How can I update the model (and the view respectively) *after* the new data arrived
in order to avoid this flickering effect?

Here is my current controller (slightly modified from [step_11 (Angular.js Tutorial)](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_11)):

```
function MyPollingCtrl($scope, $routeParams, $timeout, Model) {

(function tick() {
    $scope.line = Model.get({
        modelId : $routeParams.modelId
    }, function(model) {
        $timeout(tick, 2000);
    });
})();

}
```

// edit: I'm using the current stable 1.0.6 of Angular.js

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try updating the data in the success callback. Something like this:

```
(function tick() {
    Model.get({
        modelId : $routeParams.modelId
    }, function(model) {
        $scope.line = model;    
        $timeout(tick, 2000);
    });
})();
```

This should prevent the flicker that is occurring when `$scope.line` is empty as the Model [resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource) is fetching the data.