# Update scope properties when server data changes without client checking server angularjs

Tags: angularjs

For this method call:

```
$http.get("Some api call").then(function (response) {
                        $scope.data=response.data;
                    });
```

Suppose the `response` keeps on updating from time to time and I wish to update the `$scope.data` property whenever the `response` is updating without firing the $http.get using timeout or interval methods.

I am not getting any solution for this issue. Please provide your ideas with examples.

Comment: You can use $scope.$watch('data', function(newValue, oldValue){
    console.log('being watched oldValue:', oldValue, 'newValue:', newValue);
  }); Check if value is changed and if yes then call get

Comment: @neda Can you please provide an example

Comment: Watch the data variable like my above  comment and check if it has changed .

Comment: If the data is changing on the server, you either need to poll from the client (e.g. through setTimeout/Interval, which you want to avoid), or you can try to use something like WebSockets http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/ -- This allows a connection to be made to the server and the server to send updates to the client.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is called [Polling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671031/server-polling-with-angularjs).

Your HTTP request will NOT get the latest data unless you fire the request again. Unless you fire the request again, your `response` will not have the latest data and thus, your `data` object will also not get updated.

No amount of `$watch` will suffice. Simply because, unless you poll the server periodically, you will not get the latest data.

This is how HTTP/1.1 behaves. This is soon about to change with HTTP/2

If you do not wish to make periodic requests, then have a look at sockets. You have not mentioned your backend but a Nodejs example can be found at [socket.io](http://socket.io/).

Comment: Can the solution be developed without using any other js

Comment: "...any other js". What do you mean by this?

Comment: Like node.js or jetty as you have mentioned in your solution

Comment: No! I don't think you understand the problem. That is how HTTP behaves. No matter what your backend is. Either poll the server frequently or use sockets as mentioned.

Comment: See what all example I have seen on websockets and angularjs, all have involved nodejs/jetty but have never used solely angularjs implementation.
Also, for an rest service like "http://time.jsontest.com", how to form Websockets as I have only seen "ws" as protocol in all the examples