# AngularJS using ng-resource with multiple server polling methods

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngresource

I am using the method based on this answer: [Server polling with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671031/server-polling-with-angularjs)

But how can I set this update when I have multiple polling methods?

Here is a snippet of my service:

```
function pollingService($resource) {
    return {
        methodA: $resource(window.rootUrl + 'api/methodA', { para: '@para1' }, {
            query: { method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: false }
        }),
        methodB: $resource(window.rootUrl + 'api/methodB', {}, {
            query: { method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: false }
        })
    }
};
```

So how can I set up the tick method to poll theese 2 methods and only create 1 polling loop?

```
(function tick() {
    $scope.method1 = pollingService.methodA.query(function () {
        $timeout(tick, $scope.refreshRate);
    });
    $scope.method2 = pollingService.methodB.query(function () {
        $timeout(tick, $scope.refreshRate);
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `$q.all()`

```
(function tick() {
    var promises = [];
    promises.push(pollingService.methodA.query().$promise);
    promises.push(pollingService.methodB.query().$promise);
    $q.all(promises).then(function(results){
        var result1 = results[0]; //Result from methodA
        var result2 = results[1]; //Result from methodB
        $timeout(tick, $scope.refreshRate);
    }
})();
```

Comment: Yea, I actually concidered that. But didn't know if that was "the angular way" and if it was an easier way instead of doing it.

Comment: Well, if i would write the code, i would use `promises` and then do `$q.all(promises).then(function(){ //Code });`

Comment: Is it possible to access the promise element while it's "loading" the data? With my previous method I could access method1.$resolved in my view and it would dynamicly change between true and false when the promise was called.

Comment: I guess you can assign them to separate variables: `var query1 = pollingService.methodA.query()` `promises.push(query1.$promise)` `query1.$resolved; //What you want`

Answer (score 2):

You could use the promises `$q.all` function:

```
var myTickFunc = function() {
  return $q.all([pollingService.methodA.query().$promise, pollingService.methodA.query().$promise)
     .then(function(result){ 
            //Setup timer again
});
```

Comment: That seem to work pretty nice, only issue is the mapping of the results though. Do you just map the result[id] to the number of when the promise was added? so the first one will be result[0], second result[1] etc. Or is it any better way of mapping this?

Comment: The result from `methodA` will come first, then `methodB`. In the same order as you add the `promises` to the `array` passed to `$q.all()`.

Comment: Yep, exactly.  The results come back as an array in this example.