# send callback from nodejs backend to frontend

Tags: html, node.js, callback, response

I have got a fileUpload (made with NodeJS) and i want to show the success of the upload in the html in the {{upload.message}}. I implemented it with AngularJS but it didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

**HTML**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload"
    method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
     <input type="file" name="file" />
        <p></p>
    <input type="file" name="file" />
        <p></p>
    <input type="file" name="file" /> 
        <br> <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit"
            class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
<span>{{upload.message}}</span>
</div>
```

**NodeJS**

```
router.post('/upload', function(req,res){
    upload(req,res,function(err) {
        var fileNames = [];
        req.files.forEach(function(element){
           fileNames.push(element.filename);
        })
        console.log('Selected Files: ', fileNames);
        if(err){
            res.end("Error: '" , err , "'");
        }else{
        res.sendStatus(204);
        }
    });
});
```

**AngularJS**

```
 var self = this;
  this.message = "";

  this.upload= function(){
    $http.post('/uploads')
        .then(function success(result){
            self.message = "Upload worked";
        },
        function error(response){
            self.message = "Error upload failed";
        });
  };
```

Comment: First check your routes. You have /upload in the form and nodejs and /uploads in Angularjs. Second, you should submit the form through angular and not through regular html/action. You bind the message to the $scope and updated it after you receive 200 ok from the server. Check here [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) for submitting forms.

Answer (score 2):

**edit:** You should read this book: http://www.allitebooks.com/read/index.php?id=7630

You normally make a request from browser to the server and not the other way around. I suggest using Ajax with polling. If you insist on sending a request from the server to the browser you could use [Comet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)) (but I do not recommend that solution).

With jQuery (altough not mentioned in your question), you would write something like this to poll every x seconds:

```js
function doPoll() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/uploads",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            //Set an empty response to see the error
            xml: "<response></response>"
        },
        dataType: "text xml",
        success: function(xml, textStatus, xhr) {
            if (xhr.status == "200") {
                //do the thing you wanted to do on succes
            }
        },
        complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
            console.log(xhr.status);
        }
    });
    setTimeout(doPoll,5000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

P.S. Totally forgot about [sockets](http://socket.io/) I also like that solution, but beware sockets are not REST like HTTP.

> You should think of it like this: a browser is meant to make stateless
>   requests, not to keep open a connection, however with commet or
>   websockets it's possible. With polling which I would recommend you ask
>   the server a lot of times for the info until you get the desired
>   response.

From the wiki about Comet:

> None of the above streaming transports work across all modern browsers
>   without negative side-effects. This forces Comet developers to
>   implement several complex streaming transports, switching between them
>   depending on the browser. Consequently, many Comet applications use
>   long polling, which is easier to implement on the browser side, and
>   works, at minimum, in every browser that supports XHR. As the name
>   suggests, long polling requires the client to poll the server for an
>   event (or set of events). The browser makes an Ajax-style request to
>   the server, which is kept open until the server has new data to send
>   to the browser, which is sent to the browser in a complete response.
>   The browser initiates a new long polling request in order to obtain
>   subsequent events. Specific technologies for accomplishing
>   long-polling include the following:

Comment: I would like to have an output if the upload worked. So when I understand you right I have to do this in the Frontend, but I would like to do it with angularJS so I start with $http.post('upload', function(... ? Is that right? How do I go on to get the output in <span>{{message}}</span>

Comment: tried something with angularjs but it didn't work. Edited it above.

Comment: @nolags then you might want to look at this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671031/server-polling-with-angularjs

Comment: this isn't what I'm looking for I think. I want to show if the file was uploaded to the server and I want to tell the frontend and show it in the <span>{{message}}</span> can you tell me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: You should think of it like this: a browser is meant to make stateless requests, not to keep open a connection, however with commet or websockets it's possible. With polling which I would recommend you ask the server a lot of times for the info until you get the desired response.

Comment: Is it also possible to implement something like polling in AngularJS ?

Comment: And I don't want a open connection I just want a response when the upload finished or when the upload failed. Is this really what I need?

Comment: 5 comments up I linked you the answer for angularJS polling and yes these are 3 ways of achieving your goal that work well. I don't understand what the problem is with the solutions provided.

Comment: I don't know if I just don't get it but I don't want continuous information from the server and I think it should work somehow how I made it up with angularJS and I want to know what is wrong with my code why doesn't it give the success status to the message span?

Comment: The way you think the browser would still have to wait for a request to be send from the server. This can be done with websockets, however I would just ask for the answer every x seconds because it's easier to implement and websockets are overkill for what you want. Comet is an ugly solution as mentioned on the wiki so xhr is the best option that suits your needs.

Comment: Could you please make a fiddle how to use it with the html?

Comment: @nolags I gave a sample, it's your job to apply it to your own code!